# Android edittext onclick event handling and selection

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext, selection

I have two edit text views. If I click first, I need to select first edittext and set to second "00". Like in default android alarm clock.
My problem:

- I have api level 10, so I can't write something like:

```
firstEText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        secondEText.setText("00");
    }
});
```

If I use

```
firstEText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        secondEText.setText("00");
    }
});
```

so I need click my view twice. Possible solution:

```
firstEText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            //but with onTouch listener I have problems with 
            //edit text selection:
            ((EditText) view).setSelection(0, ((EditText) view).getText().length());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

so my .setSelection does not always work. OMG! Help me please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to do the following:

- When focusing `firstEText`, select all the text within `firstEText` and set `secondEText` to *"00"*.

What I don't understand is why you say you cannot use `setOnFocusChangeListener`, since, [it is available since API 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29).

A convenient attribute to select all the text of an *EditText* when getting focus on an element, is [android:selectAllOnFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelectAllOnFocus%28boolean%29), which does exactly what you want. Then, you just need to set `secondEText` to *"00"*.

**UI**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

**Activity**

```
firstEText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
secondEText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

firstEText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            secondEText.setText("00");
        }
    }

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I make it programmaticaly? I add my all my views in code.

Comment: Yes, sure. This attribute can be set also from Java. Do something like firstEText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

Comment: @Leo If you think this answer has satisfactorily solved your question, please remember to mark it as "accepted" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work